# How to install and configure gitlab-CE on a local CentOS 7?

Tags: installation, gitlab, centos, gitlab-ce

I have manually installed GitLab Community Edition (gitlab-ce) on my CentOS 7 server, which has 2 CPUs and 8GB of memory. The installation process went smoothly, and I have kept all configurations at their default settings, except for the **external_url** option, which I set to my server's IP address.

After running gitlab-ctl reconfigure and restarting GitLab, I waited for over half an hour, but I am still unable to access GitLab. Even attempting to access it locally using wget **http://127.0.0.1:8080** on the server machine results in a 502 Bad Gateway response.

I have also consulted with GPT-3.5 for troubleshooting suggestions, but no further solutions were provided.
I just only modified one option "external_url" on gitlab.rb, all others kept.
My set is:

```
external_url 'http://172.19.0.1:8080'
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: According to https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/operations/puma.html, I changed external_url, and puma['port'] to separated listening ipaddress and port, it still doesn't work.

Comment: I resolved the issue.
It's caused by "gitaly" and "prometheus" service unavailable.
For "gitaly" service, check the log, some directories had not be created with default settings by some unknown issue. In generally, log default path is "
For "prometheus" service, since my server can't reach external internet, I have to change configuration yaml file to localhost IP address.

Another best precise is to keep 80 port for gitlab since a lot of port will be used by many support services, that's will be more easier to setup it correct.

Comment: BTW, I wanna prefer mention that I resolved this issue by GPT-3.5. It's good to help you troubleshooting.